# htaccess url redirection with excluding few of existing URLS

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Here is my Problem

I have 10 URLS on a website A

1. I want to redirect 2 URLS (out of 10) from Website A to Website B via .htaccess
2. I want that 4 URLS from the list should never be redirected to anywhere
3. I want that remaining 4 URLS should be redirected to Website C
4. And Anyother URL from website A should redirect to Website D

Can any body help ?

```
Redirect /percussion/21021-crossing-grip-extensions  http://myblog.tumblr.com/thisURL
Redirect /percussion/21045-indoor-percussion-circuits http://myblog.tumblr.com/thisURL
Redirect /percussion/21047-26-standard-rudiments-on-social-media http://myblog.tumblr.com/thisURL

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wind-instruments/38250-hd200-excerpt-video
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/namm-2015-products/49480-gc1ta
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/namm-2015-products/49485-u1ta-2015
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/namm-2015-products/49486-a6r-a-series-2015


RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://www.codephun.com/$1 [R=301]
```

Comment: Clarify what is the problem with your existing rules?

Comment: Is this your complete .htaccess or you have other code as well?

Comment: Here is pastebin URL http://pastebin.com/7XwRHXni thanks

Comment: The only problem is that rest of the links which are supposed to redirect to  codephun.com doesn't redirect. but if i use [R=301,L] then it does redirect to the site but then First links with "redirect" command also start to redirect to codePhun.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a huge .htaccess file. I will provide few tips that you can use to fix your problem.

1. Don't use `Redirect` directive, just have your rules using `RewriteRule` itself.
2. Use `THE_REQUEST` variable instead of `REQUEST_URI` as `THE_REQUEST` variable that represents original request received by Apache from your browser and it doesn't get overwritten after execution of some rewrite rules.

So for the snippet shown above use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^percussion/21021-crossing-grip-extensions  http://myblog.tumblr.com/thisURL [L,NC,R=302]
RewriteRule ^percussion/21045-indoor-percussion-circuits http://myblog.tumblr.com/thisURL [L,NC,R=302]
RewriteRule ^percussion/21047-26-standard-rudiments-on-social-media http://myblog.tumblr.com/thisURL [L,NC,R=302]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/wind-instruments/38250-hd200-excerpt-video
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/namm-2015-products/49480-gc1ta
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/namm-2015-products/49485-u1ta-2015
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/namm-2015-products/49486-a6r-a-series-2015
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://www.codephun.com/$1 [R=301]

# Rest of the Joomla rules come here
```